# SQL hierarchical data

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I have the following requirement in sql server where I need to report data of children of catg "FIN" which are direct descendants of a parent.

**Input**

```
parent,child,parent_catg,child_catg
A   A   FIN FIN
A   B   FIN FIN
B   B   FIN FIN
A   C   FIN FIN
B   C   FIN FIN
C   C   FIN FIN
B   D   FIN FIN
C   D   FIN FIN
E   E   OTH OTH
E   F   OTH OTH
A   G   FIN FIN
B   G   FIN FIN
A   H   FIN FIN
P   P   FIN FIN
P   Q   FIN FIN
```

**Output**

```
Eligible children for reporting
B
H
Q
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic.  It is not obvious.

Comment: Also please show what queries you've tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a coding service, and it's difficult to nodge you in the right direction without knowing where exactly you're stuck. We expect a minimal amount of effort and research from the person asking the question.

Comment: How can `B` and `C` be their own parents? In a hierarchy that would create a infinite loop.`A` is the parent of `B` is the parent of `B` is the parent of `B` is the parent of `B` is the parent of `B` is the parent of `B`... is the parent of `B` is the parent of `B`... You get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group by and count(). ie:

```
 select child 
 from myTable
 where child_catg = 'FIN' and parent <> child
 group by child
 having count(*) = 1;
```